# TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 0 found

Tags: python, image, ord

I was given this school project, which goal is to take a picture, apply the RLE method in order to compress it in a binary file (.txt), and save some space. And after struglling with it for 3 days now I'm having troubles.

```
def read():
    f2=open("data2.txt",'rb') #open a binary file in reading mod.
    im3=zeros((962,800,3),dtype="uint8") #create picture which size is 962*800 where every pixels are coded on 3 bytes.
    d=0#pixel counter
    i=0#lign indexation
    j=0#column indexation
    b=ord(f2.read(1))# the informations are read a first time
    a=ord(f2.read(1))
    red=ord(f2.read(1))
    green=ord(f2.read(1))
    blue=ord(f2.read(1))
    while i!=im3.shape[0]: #as long as it doesn't reach the final lign
        if d<=(a+b*255):
            im3[i,j,0] = red
            im3[i,j,1] = green
            im3[i,j,2] = blue
            d+=1
            j+=1
            if j==im3.shape[1]:
                j=0
                i+=1
        else: #resets pixel counter and starts reading next informations
            d=0
            b=ord(f2.read(1))
            a=ord(f2.read(1))
            red=ord(f2.read(1))
            green=ord(f2.read(1))
            blue=ord(f2.read(1))       
    f2.close()
    imsave("done.bmp",im3)
    return im3

imshow(read());
show();
```

When I execute the pgrm, it gives me this error written in the tittle. Which is something I feel like impossible to correct, since it is writting itself in hex.

Here's further information :
A pixel is not coded here using bytes, like we usually do on format such as .bmp.
Here RLE will search for identic pixel on a same lign, and count how many times it encounters it, by comparing 3 levels colors. Finally it stores in two additional bytes than the RGB ones : a and b.
a is for the number of pixels.
b is the number of 255 stacks of pixels. (Since I'm coding data into 8bits and that pictures are usually larger than 255*255 size)

Comment: The error indicates that one of your `f2.read(1)` calls returned an empty string; that happens when you have reached the end of the file.

Comment: Well in that case, how can I prevent it ?

Comment: Without the actual file input data, hard to say. Your file doesn't contain as much info as you expect it to contain.

Comment: Moreover, i'd like to share the file data2 to show everybody how it gets stuck. Does anyone knows a site where I could store that binary file?

Comment: You really want to study the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html), and avoid so many individual byte reads and `ord()` calls. Reading an integer from 2 bytes is trivial with that module.

Comment: So you have a 2-byte number, followed by 3 bytes encoding the RGB value: `repeat, r, g, b = struct.unpack('>HBBB', f.read(5))` would give you those in one step. Create an array of width * height by 3, not a width by height by 3 array, and reshape afterwards.

Comment: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/files/1585990/data2.txt

Comment: Here is the link to the file

Comment: Ok i will try that

Comment: Nope, that failed. Moreover I tried installing the struct module, wich didn't go well too.

Comment: Are you 100% certain you have the format correct? I'm trying to read that data and I don't get a coherent image from it.

Comment: Um, the `struct` module is a part of python.

Answer (score 2):

Your file is too short, your ran out of data. `file.read(..)` returns an empty string when the EOF is found. Perhaps your remaining bytes should just be left at 0?

You are reading your data extremely inefficiently. Use the [`struct` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to unpack your data into integers, and create a single long numpy array of (R, G, B) triplets, then *reshape* the data to form your image matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import struct

def lecture_fichier_compresse():
    width, height = 800, 962
    with open("data2.txt", 'rb') as rle_data:
        image = np.zeros((width * height, 3), dtype="uint8")
        pos = 0
        # decompress RLE data; 2 byte counter followed by 3 RGB bytes
        # read until the file is done
        for data in iter(lambda: rle_data.read(5), ''):
            if len(data) < 5:
                # not enough data to store another RLE RGB chunk
                break
            count, r, g, b = struct.unpack('>HBBB', data)
            image[pos:pos + count, :] = [[r, g, b]] * count
            pos += count
    # reshape continuous stream into an image matrix
    image = image.reshape((height, width, 3))
    imsave("Copie_compresse.bmp",im3)
    return image
```

That said, using your sample file data I can't seem to construct a coherent image. Decompression produces data for 695046 pixels, which doesn't make for a coherent rectangular image (the highest short dimension that numbers factors into is 66, so extremely elongated). Even allowing for missing data at the end I can't seem to find any aspect ratio that produces a coherent image. The conclusion is that your input data is incomplete or incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, however this is too advanced for me.

Comment: @Oni_chan: it does the *exact same work*, only more efficient, and taking into account that the file doesn't contain enough data.

Comment: But yeah now that you say that, the file is indeed too short. I just need a way to make it stop reading the moment it hits the last package of data

Comment: @Oni_chan: the image dimensions are clearly wrong, the image rows don't line up.

Comment: Well its dimensions are 962*800 vertically then horizontaly

Comment: @Oni_chan: but there is not enough data for that. There is data for 695046 RGB triplets, which makes for a weird image (66 x 10531 is the best factor I can find). You'd need 769600 bytes of info to produce a 800 x 962 image.

Comment: Don't worry about it anymore. I found the multiple bugs. The problem weren't in my logic, rather vicious mistakes in putting resets variables and even the function to decode it.

Comment: Martijn Pieters : But I thank you nonetheless. Have a great day sir !